# c++ A structure (or class) with specific function for each instanced object

Tags: c++, callback, function-pointers

I need to implement a structure (or class) where each instance has a "pointer" to a specific function. Is this possible?

Something like this:

```
struct constrain{

  string                              name;
  int                            direction;
  double evaluate (vector <double> &x_var);
};
```

Where *evaluate* "points" to a specific function, so that when I create my *constrain* object I can tell to which function the object method *evaluate* should point to and when I later use it (e.g. my *constrain* objects will be contained within a std::vector) I can call the specific function.

Comment: Does evaluate need to access the `this` pointer?

Comment: Use reference to pass `x_var`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `std::function`:

```
struct Foo
{
    std::function<double (std::vector<double>)> func;
};
```

It's better to pass `vector` by reference as pmr suggested. Here is the full example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

struct Foo
{
    std::function<double (const std::vector<double> &)> func;
};

static double calc(const std::vector<double> &params)
{
    return 10.0;
}

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    f.func = calc;

    std::vector<double> v;
    std::cout << f.func(v) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If your `STL` implementation does not have `std::function` consider using `boost::function`

Comment: And consider that passing a vector by value is possibly not the right thing to do.

Comment: @pmr: You are right, but it's how the vector is passed in the question

Comment: You are assuming his compiler (or his STL implementation) already have these.

Comment: That was solely directed at OP. I felt confident that this was going to become the accepted answer. You might want to add a paragraph about the differences between runtime/compile time and extend this to use a template and a functor.

Comment: my first question on stackoverflow.. very impressed! Thank you, I'm going to try this implementation :-) (I'm using g++ 4.6 and 4.4 on MinGW)

Comment: @pmr: I don't see a reason to use a template/functor here instead of `std::function` actually

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible. You need to slightly change your definition:

```
struct constrain{

  string                              name;
  int                            direction;
  double  (*evaluate)(vector <double> x_var);
};
```

However, this is a bit C-ish approach. Since you are using c++, you can use function objects (the ones with overloaded `operator()`).

Answer (score 0):

create constructor where one of arguments is pointer on function:

```
constraint::constraint (double (*pFn)(vector <double> x_var))
{
    this->evaluate = pFn
}
```

also in header correct:

```
double  (*evaluate) (vector <double> x_var);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with pointers to functions or functors (for example from boost).

Try something like this:

```
struct constrain{
  string                              name;
  int                            direction;
  double  (*evaluate) (vector <double> &x_var);
};
```

or

```
struct constrain{
  string                              name;
  int                            direction;
  boost::function<double(vector &<double>)> evaluate;
};
```

Just note, that this will not have any pointer to "object" it was called from, so you have to add proper parameter (and probably typedef it for convenience):

```
struct constrain{
  typedef double  (*callback_t) (constrain *obj, vector <double> &x_var);
  string                              name;
  int                            direction;
  callback_t evaluate_f;

  // helper function
  double evaluate(vector <double> &x_var) {
    return evaluate_f(this, x_var);
  }
};
```

Check http://ideone.com/VlAvD for usage.

It could be much simpler if using `boost::function` and `boost::bind` (or `std::*` equivalents if you are using compiler with C++11): http://ideone.com/wF8Bz

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
We do have pointers to function
Once you create such a pointer you can just **instantiate it with the address of** function.

Example

```
void my_int_func(int x)
{
    printf( "%d\n", x );
}

int main()
{
    void (*foo)(int); // this is a pointer to a function
    foo = &my_int_func;

    return 0;
}
```

Similarly you can use the structure member pointer as a pointer to a function